# What does "listPointer->leftPointer->rightPointer = newNodePtr;" do?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

It is my first time encountering this type of pointer. It points then points again, what does this imply? I encountered this on a doubly linked list program.

```
listPointer->leftPointer->rightPointer = newNodePtr;
```

Comment: There isn't _really_ any way to understand this without knowing the type of `listPointer` and finding either its documentation or its class definition (e.g. with the `class` or `struct` keywords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably is part of inserting a new element. If you do it correctly, you only need to know about the element *after* where you wish to insert it, and the element you are inserting. The other element can be gotten by following the links.

Starting from

```
             listPtr
                |
                v
----------  ----------
|        |->|        |
| Node L |  |  Node  |
|        |<-|        |
----------  ----------

newNodePtr
   |
   v
----------
|        |
| Node N |
|        |
----------
```

First do

```
listPointer->leftPointer->rightPointer = newNodePtr;
```

So that the preceding element points to the new element

```
               newNodePtr    listPtr
                  |             |
                  v             v
----------    ----------    ----------
|        |--->|        |    |        |
| Node L |    | Node N |    |  Node  |
|        |<-| |        |  |-|        |
----------  | ----------  | ----------
            |             |
            |-------------|
```

Then do

```
newNodePtr->leftPointer = listPointer->leftPointer;
```

So that the new element points to the preceding element

```
               newNodePtr    listPtr
                  |             |
                  v             v
----------    ----------    ----------
|        |--->|        |    |        |
| Node L |<---| Node N |    |  Node  |
|        |<-| |        |  |-|        |
----------  | ----------  | ----------
            |             |
            |-------------|
```

Then do

```
listPointer->leftPointer = newNodePtr;
```

So that the following element points back to the new element

```
             newNodePtr  listPtr
                |           |
                v           v
----------  ----------  ----------
|        |->|        |  |        |
| Node L |  | Node N |  |  Node  |
|        |<-|        |<-|        |
----------  ----------  ----------
```

Then finally

```
newNodePtr->rightPointer = listPointer;
```

So that the new element points at the following element

```
             newNodePtr  listPtr
                |           |
                v           v
----------  ----------  ----------
|        |->|        |->|        |
| Node L |  | Node N |  |  Node  |
|        |<-|        |<-|        |
----------  ----------  ----------
```

Answer (score 1):

> It points then points again, what does this imply?

The code implies that there's a kind of

```
struct Node {
    Node* leftPointer;
    Node* rightPointer;
};
```

which is used *recursively* to build a tree.

`listPointer` is declared as

```
Node* listPointer;
```

`newNodePtr` is declared as

```
 Node* newNodePtr;
```

The tricky part will be to manage that all of these pointers have properly allocated memory to point to when

```
listPointer->leftPointer->rightPointer = newNodePtr;
```

is executed at runtime.

---

Regarding a doubly linked list as you tagged your question so:

I'd prefer a different naming of the `struct` and its members

```
struct DoubleLinkedListItem {
    DoubleLinkedListItem* previous;
    DoubleLinkedListItem* next;
};
```

for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe used to remove `listPointer` from the link list like mentioned below:

```
listPointer->leftPointer->rightPointer = newNodePtr;
newNodePtr->rightPointer = listPointer
```